# Dynamic meta_query depending on query var paramters in url Wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress, query-variables

In my custom post type i want to filter depending on the parameters in the url. For example `?car=yellow&foo=1` refer to meta query key and value. The key and value's are the extra fields. What makes it extra difficult is that

This is what my loop looks like right now:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'glas', // Your post type name
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if($loop->have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <?php echo get_field('type_glas'); ?> <?php echo get_field('uitvoering_glas'); ?><br>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages; ?>
    <?php if ($total_pages > 1) : ?>
        <?php
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't have time to write a full example, but basically you need to register your query vars (car, foo) and then add additional args to your $args array using meta_query. Like if(isset(get_query_var('car')) ... this is basically a suggestion to begin your googling. what you seek is not hard per say.

Comment: It's not hard to add 
```
'meta_query' => array(
  'relation'  => 'AND',
  array(
   'key'  => 'foo',
   'value'  => 'bar',
   'compare' => '='
  ),
  array(
   'key'  => 'x',
   'value'  => 'y',
   'compare' => '='
  ),
 )
```
To the WP_query to get the result. But i want to do this depending on the query in the url. If need i also want to ad another key and value comparison

Comment: Googled register query vars. I think this wil get me on the way

Comment: Yes, so you put the conditional in - if isset query var, $args['meta_query'] = array()... you put that in after the args are declared exactly as you have it now. You can always add individual items to the args array based on conditions. Just put them in before you run wp_query and it should work out

Comment: [I found the answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55831/conditional-arguments-for-wp-query-and-tax-query-depending-on-if-somevar-has-a) Thank you @kai